# Getting `path/to/protobuf/BUILD.bazel:398:26`: output 'unittest_gen_import_pb2.py' was not created error while running Protobuf examples

Tags: protocol-buffers, bazel

I was trying to understand protobuf, so I was running these [examples](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/main/examples). I was trying to run `bazel build :all` as the README suggested. But when I ran it I got these errors

```
ERROR: path/to/Projects/protobuf/BUILD.bazel:398:26: output 'unittest_gen_import_pb2.py' was not created
ERROR: path/to/Projects/protobuf/BUILD.bazel:398:26: ProtoCompile unittest_gen_import_pb2.py failed: not all outputs were created or valid
INFO: Elapsed time: 155.339s, Critical Path: 21.19s
INFO: 1409 processes: 255 internal, 1132 darwin-sandbox, 22 worker.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I am not really sure where to start debugging as I am not super familiar with Bazel. Any tips? Thank you!

Comment: If you can share more details on which Bazel version and OS you are using, then would be helpful to narrow down the issue and community can help you this.

Comment: oh true. 

Bazel Version = bazel 6.3.1
OS = Mac Ventura 13.0.1

Let me know if you want the java version as well